# Eclipse shows XML errors even with all validators disabled and an XML Catalog defined

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I have just upgraded to Eclipse 2023-09 from 2020-06 and I'm getting a lot of XML errors.
For example I have a custom XML with an XSD.  I have added that XSD to the XML Catalog of Eclipse, in the Preferences I have also checked "Suspend all validators" and performed the "full rebuild", but I'm still getting errors.

[image: xml]

The error at line #1 is:

> vc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mapping'.

The error at line #4 is:

> Downloading external resources is disabled.

This is how I have added the XSD to the Catalog:

[image: catalog]

And this is a fragment of the XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://myapp.mycompany.com/schema/mapping"
           targetNamespace="http://myapp.mycompany.com/schema/mapping">

    <xs:element name="mapping">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
```

I have also several SOAP XML files without a schema that generate errors like:

> cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'order' to a type definition for element 'orders'.

Any web page about this topic is very old and I have even found [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338759) about validators that has still "Status: NEW" after many years.

What's happening?  My projects work fine, so I dont' want to see these XML errors because they could hide real errors.  Please, help!

Comment: Downloading external resources such as .xsd files has been disabled by default for security reasons for quite some time. Either you enable it or add it the XML catalog. There are two XML editors (from Eclipse WTP and Eclipse Wild Web Developer) each using their own XML catalog and with own preferences. You referring two a bug report that is inactive for seven years and which is about validation of JavaScript files, not about XML files.

Comment: @howlger, yes, I don't want to download the XSD. That's why I'm using the catalog.  But it is ignored.  In the "Open with" dialog I see just one XML editor even if I have two catalogs in the preferences (the 2nd one must be customized editing an XML, not nice).  And I have also **suspended validators** so why those errors?

Comment: @howlger, editing the catalog of "Wild Web Developer" worked, thanks!  However I still have many other errors in SOAP files that have no XSD, that's why I disable validators.  Any idea?

Comment: ...and disabling validation in "Wild Web Developer" removes the errors from the "Problems" view, but **not** the red markers from the XML editor.  It seems a bug.  Furthermore the "Suspend all validators" should work on "Wild Web developer" too.  So where is the other XML editor that uses the "classic" Eclipse catalog?

Comment: After having updated the "wild" component, the red markers in the editor disappeared but the "Suspend all validators" switch is not yet integrated with this component.

Comment: In the _Problems_ view, delete the errors and warnings and check whether they come back by _Project > Clean_ or by opening the file. If they come back, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe exactly what project settings and preferences do you have (be aware that project settings can overwrite the workspace preferences). XML files can be opened with the _XML Editor_ (Eclipse WTP) or the _Generic Text Editor_ (Eclipse Wild Web Developer). The XML language server can also be disabled in the preferences.